# Install oauth.dll with PHP 8.1 on Windows 11

Tags: php, windows, apache, oauth

I have a PHP application that requires `oauth` to connect to a third party.

Previously, on `PHP 7.1` and below, I've managed to:

1. Download a version from here: https://pecl.php.net/package/oauth/2.0.7/windows
2. Stick the `dll` in my PHP `ext` folder
3. Enable the extension in `php.ini`
4. Restart apache

**However**, that doesn't seem to work with PHP 8.1 as I get the following error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oauth' (tried: C:/PHP/8.1.3/ext\oauth (The specified module could not be found), C:/PHP/8.1.3/ext\php_oauth.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

I read online that `oauth v2.0.7` is supported for `PHP 7.1+` but that doesn't seem to be the case unless I'm doing something wrong.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.